# How do I address this error "object 'multiprocess' is not exported by 'namespace:future'" when trying to install spinR?

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm trying to install the package spinR and I'm getting this error and I don't know what it means:
Error: object 'multiprocess' is not exported by 'namespace:future'

I'm fairly new to R any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I ran:
`devtools::install_gitlab('jbferet/spinR', lib = 'C:/win-library/4.0')`

I also tried reinstalling future:
`install.packages("future", lib = 'C:/win-library/4.0')`

But I still got the same error: object 'multiprocess' is not exported by 'namespace:future'

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this error, too, for a different package. The problem is not in `future` but the library you're installing, in your case `spinR`. `multiprocess` from `future` has long been deprecated, but in March of 2023, it finally went defunct, meaning when `spinR` tries to import it, it fails. In short, this is something the `spinR` devs should address. As of today (Aug 07, 2023) it seems the `NAMESPACE` file in the repo was updated c. 2 weeks ago, and no longer includes `importFrom(future,multiprocess)`. This should fix your issue after you update the package. You can try using `update.packages()`, but since it looks like you're installing the development version, you may need to use `remove.packages(<the package name>)` and then reinstall.

I hope this helps. I'm new to R myself, but wanted to share what I had found in case its helpful.